# Why is my loop producing empty <option></option> tags in my <select>?

Tags: php, html, select, tags, replace

I have the following code:

```
<?php 
        $a= 11;
        echo "<select name='rabboSelect' style='width:300px;'>";
        $sqlQuery="SELECT * FROM writers";
        $result=sql($sqlQuery);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $a .= "<option value='" .$row["ID"]."'>" . $row["name"] . "<option>";
        }
        echo str_replace("<option></option>", "", $a);;
        echo "</select>";
        ?>
```

and in the html it's adding `<option></option>` after each one, even if I try to delete it:

```
<select name="rabboSelect" style="width:300px;">11<option value="2">הרב מילר</option><option></option><option value="3">משה דוויד</option><option></option><option value="4">קלמי גריינמן</option><option></option><option value="5">בנימין יעבץ</option><option></option><option value="8">אליהו פרץ</option><option></option></select>
```

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? is not clear with your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I wonder why you are setting `$a=11;` - did you maybe mean `$a='';`?

Next, you are missing a `/` in the closing `option` tag. If you tried View Source rather than viewing the DOM, you'd see that rather than the extra options.

Comment: tank you very much its was very helpful

Comment: This is correct. You're never outputting a `</option>`, so the browser is closing the tags for you. However, because you output one `<option value=...>` tag and one `<option>` tag, the browser is inserting two closing `</option>`s, after each opening `<option>`.